# Facebook 'like' button in Firefox 42 Browser not showing up

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox

I have put 'like' buttons on various pages of my website according to the Facebook guidelines. I see them all perfectly in I.E, Chrome, Opera, and Safari - all of which are up to date versions. However, when I check in Firefox, which is up to date with version 42, the "like' buttons are not there, and do not load on a refresh. Any fix for this... thanks

Answer (score 3):

Put in your web site then look to the left of the address bar. If you see a shield click it and it gives you the option to 'Disable Protection'. A feature that FF gave us but didn't bother to tell us they did.

Answer (score 2):

FB Like button and like box can be seen only if you disable the protection on the left side of the Firefox search bar (you can do it clicking on the shield icon). Pretty annoying and not good for business at all. I hope Firefox improves itself as soon as possible and I also hope people aren't upgrading older versions of it. Really bad indeed